# Does "anglophone" refer to anyone who speaks English?

Tags: word-meaning

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anglophone):

> anglophone
> a person who speaks English, especially in countries where
> other languages are also spoken.

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anglophone):

> anglophone
> consisting of or belonging to an English-speaking population
> especially in a country where two or more languages are spoken.

Does this mean that anyone who speaks English, whether native or non-native and regardless of where they live, is an anglophone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "a person who speaks English," or "[a member of] an English-speaking population". It doesn't mean a native speaker, but it does suggest that the person uses English as their normal means of communication. Very often it is used to refer to people who are native speakers, because it is used to contrast with those people who primarily speak another language

But meanings are not mathematical definitions.  Meaning has to be understood in context.

So, for example, in Canada, an anglophone is a person who speaks English *in contrast to the francophone Quebecois*.  A non-native Indian person, living in Canada but using English might be part of the Anglophone community. A French Canadian, even though they are a fluent English speaker, isn't.

Answer (score 1):

#### It's usually a cultural term.

I would say that it's usually used to refer to someone by the culture they're from; when it's used, it's used to refer to someone from an English-speaking country. In particular, it usually refers to someone from the "anglophone countries": the UK, Ireland, the USA, Canada, Australia, and New Zealand. In short, the UK, and the countries where its colonists formed the dominant ethnic group.

In the case of Canada and Ireland, which have smaller, non-English-speaking communities of Europeans within them, it'd refer to people from the dominant, English-speaking culture; non-European groups of indigenous peoples would usually be referred to using other terms, unless they've assimilated into the dominant Anglophone culture.

Certain former British colonies, such as South Africa and India, might also still have anglophone communities descended from the English-speaking colonists, though their countries wouldn't be classified as "anglophone countries" since the majority of the population speaks other languages (often because their indigenous peoples form a dominant part of their population, rather than the European colonizers).